# Apply setinterval on only one element

Tags: javascript, jquery

i use this code

```
var auto_refresh = setInterval(
function (){

        if (!localStorage) {
            return false;
        }

        if (!localStorage['VLR_CountMinichat']) {
            localStorage.setItem("VLR_CountMinichat", 0);
        }

        getnumber = localStorage.getItem("VLR_CountMinichat");
        $("#ajax-test").load("/ajax", {
            VLR_CountMinichat: getnumber
        });

}, 20000);
```

for get variable of localStorage and reload in ajax, but i want to active it if only #ajax-test is present on the page, because it's a function reserved to logged users, how to do that ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just test for length, to ensure availability.

```
$(function(){

   //.... 
   var $ajaxTest = $("#ajax-test"), auto_refresh;
   if($ajaxTest.length){
         auto_refresh = setInterval(runAjax, 20000);
   }

  function runAjax(){

    if (!localStorage) {
        return false;
    }

    if (!localStorage['VLR_CountMinichat']) {
        localStorage.setItem("VLR_CountMinichat", 0);
    }

    var getnumber = localStorage.getItem("VLR_CountMinichat");
    $ajaxTest.load("/ajax", {
        VLR_CountMinichat: getnumber
    });
 }
});
```

Comment: +1, solid answer. But dude...you are seriously way too fast, you already have an answer before I can't even type `$(function(){`.